# How can i prove Ignoring end carry using calculator with 2's complement?

Tags: calculator, twos-complement

Using 4-bit calculator with 2's complement,
For example, when putting -5 (1011) plus -2 (1101) in calculator,
End-carry comes out
10011
In My book, It says with 1's complement you have to add this
End-carry again.
But with 2's complement you just ignore End-carry.
But In the book, reason for ignoring is not written...
Sure, I know that when you ignore the end-carry It's the answer.
Is there any other reason for ignoring end-carry?

Is there any proof for ignoring end-carry?